# Symfony 2.3.1 - arrange label in two rows

Tags: symfony, label, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I have this long label in my twig view file.

```
 <div class="grid1 campoTestoMedium last " >  {{ forms.generic_input(edit_form.field, "This is indeed a very long label, my layout isn't nice anymore") }}</div>
```

I've tried by putting a `\n` or a `<br>` in the middle of it, but maybe my solution was a little bit optimistic.

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Wow, symfont 2.3.1 is quite old, not sure what generic_input is, I never saw that before, but what do you get when you add a <br>?

Comment: Expected name or number in .html.twig at line 251.

Comment: When you use `\n` add pipe of the string `|nl2br`. So it should be `{{ forms.generic_input(edit_form.field, "Long \n Label"|nl2br) }}`